# UPDATE table SET 1='yes' WHERE id='$userID'" is not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following code:

```
$updateCode = mysql_query("UPDATE pages SET pageCode='$code' WHERE id='$userID' AND pageOrder='1'");

$updateProgress = mysql_query("UPDATE progress SET 1='yes' WHERE id='$userID'");

$updateRewards = mysql_query("UPDATE earnedRewards SET 1='yes' WHERE id='$userID'");
```

The first UPDATE works just fine and the `pages` table is updated. However, the second two UPDATES don't work and the 1 column in `progress` and `earnedRewards` is not updated to 'yes'.

Any thoughts on why the second two UPDATES aren't working?

Comment: add "or die(mysql_error())" after your queries - this will show you if you have any errors in your query

Comment: Your column is named "1"? That surprises me that is allowed.

Comment: Is you column-name really 1? You should consider changing it to something else, more explaining. And are you sure your $userID is correct? Running this query in phpMyAdmin (or similar), what happens?

Comment: @MarkRummel Please be aware that this kind of code is (or might be) vulnerable to SQL injections. You need to make sure that `$userID` is sanitized (e.g. cast to int or escaped).

Comment: Even if the column is named "1" your `UPDATE` isn't attempting to access it, but rather attempting to reassign the literal integer `1`.

Comment: Nayena: I got the following error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1='yes' WHERE id='1'' at line 1. Thanks for your suggestion. I'm new to PHP and that is good to remember to use the mysql_error.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I changed the column name to start with a letter and it worked just fine.

Comment: @middus Can you expound on what you're saying about SQL injection vulnerability with $userID?

Comment: @MarkRummel It depends where its value is coming from. Say you take it from `$_GET['userid']`. That would be dangerous, because someone could put this value into this paramter `12' OR id = id; --`. Bad things could happen ;). So to avoid this, ensure that `$userID`'s value is numeric (cast it to `int`). With user-supplied strings, you should use `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The column name is 1??? You should change the column name

Comment: I changed the column name to start with a letter and everything worked just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If 1 is really your column name, you'd need to escape it with backticks.

```
UPDATE progress SET `1`='yes' WHERE id='$userID'
```

If you're trying to reference the column positionally (i.e., the first column of the table), don't. Use the column's name.

Comment: Is it even possible to have a column named `1`? If so: what the hell were you thinking, MySQL-devs!?

Comment: @middus: It's possible. Quoting [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html): "Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits."

Comment: Seriously, why would one want to allow this? This is just a train wreck waiting to happen.

Comment: @middus: I agree it's a terrible column name. But, if something *can* be done, I'll guarantee you someone's going to do it.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli Thanks! I've changed the column name to start with a letter and it all works now.

Comment: Yes, therefore, if I were a MySQL dev, I wouldn't allow a purely numeric column name :). That's what I was trying to say.